# What are academic resources that provide open source lecture notes?

Tags: teaching, lecture-notes, course-design

I have just answered a similar question on *ResearchGate* website and thought that it could also be beneficial for the *Academia.SE* community to share my answer here as well (as a wiki). Obviously, corrections and contributions are very welcome. Please see my answer (initial wiki post) below.

Comment: It looks like I don't have enough privileges to convert this Q&A into wiki - moderators, please help in that regard. Thanks.

Comment: To those who voted to close this question as off-topic: please clarify how this Q&A (on open course notes and textbooks) is _not_ about academia.

Comment: Re: the cited reason for closing. As I said from the beginning, this Q&A is intended to be a wiki collection of useful academic resources on the topic. Therefore, it IMHO doesn't belong to the category of "shopping" questions and, thus, should be reopened and converted to wiki post, as requested.

Comment: Have you tried to ask on the meta?

Comment: @Ooker: I don't feel a need for this. I have provided my arguments and, if people disagree with them or ignore them, then so be it. I value my time more than an opportunity to defend a single question from closing.

Comment: If you want a Q&A here, that's fine. But, where is the question in your question?

Comment: @scaaahu: The question is in the title. It about resources, but it's a valid question anyway (for wiki, that is).

Answer (score 3):

There exist a significant number of *repositories* that, in one way or another, contain *open source lecture notes* and similar or related information materials.

First and foremost, large **open courseware repositories** contain information on various courses, for many, including course notes. For example:

- [MIT OpenCourseWare](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses);
- [Open Course Library](http://opencourselibrary.org/course) by *Washington State Board for Community and Technical Colleges*;
- [repository and search engine](http://www.oeconsortium.org/courses) by *The Open Education Consortium*.

The second significant source is represented by a multitude of **repositories of open source textbooks** on various subjects. Such repositories include:

- [OpenStax College repository](https://www.openstaxcollege.org/books);
- [Open Textbook Library](http://open.umn.edu/opentextbooks) by *Open Textbook Network*;
- [MERLOT repository](http://www.merlot.org/merlot/materials.htm) by *California State University System* and its partners;
- [Open Textbooks repository](http://oerconsortium.org/discipline-specific) by *Community College Consortium for Open Educational Resources*;
- [Open Access Textbooks project](http://www.openaccesstextbooks.org) by *Florida Distance Learning Consortium*;
- [College Open Textbooks search engine](http://www.collegeopentextbooks.org) by *The College Open Textbooks Collaborative*;
- [The Global Text Project](http://globaltext.terry.uga.edu/books);
- [Wikibooks](https://www.wikibooks.org) and [Wikiversity](https://www.wikiversity.org) projects.

Finally, additional stream of information can be traced to **individual university departments, groups, and labs**. Usually, such resources are quite narrow in their coverage and might apply to specific areas of a discipline or a course. For example, see the *ETH*'s [open source course notes on advanced methods and strategies in organic chemistry](http://www.bode.ethz.ch/lecturenote). Also, many (IMHO, most) *individual professors* share their own course notes on their personal university-affiliated websites.